How to linearly combine the components of $\ell=2$ Cartesian tensor to ensure that the transformation matrix is orthogonal?
A Cartesian tensor of rank 2 should can be decomposed into 3 irreducible part:
$$X=\frac{1}{3}tr(X)I + \frac{1}{2}(X-X^T) + \frac{1}{2}(X+X^T-\frac{2}{3}tr(X)I)$$
and $S=\frac{1}{2}(X+X^T-\frac{2}{3}tr(X)I)$ has 5 independent components, which corresponding to $\ell=2$ spherical tensor.
However, the transformation matrix between $\ell=2$ spherical tensor is unitary (Wigner-D matrix), and the transformation matrix for ($S_{00}, S_{01}, S_{02}, S_{11}, S_{12}$) is not. I try to linearly combine them as shown in Table of spherical harmonics, but the transformation matrix is still not unitary.
So my question is that is it possible to linearly combine these components to make the transformation matrix unitary?
I got the transformation matrix between S by:
def make_l2(n, R):
    x = torch.zeros((n, 5), dtype=torch.complex64)
    y = torch.zeros((n, 5), dtype=torch.complex64)
    for i in range(n):
        t = torch.randn(2, 3)
        a = torch.einsum('i,j->ij', t[0], t[1])
        yz, xz, xy, xx, yy, zz = (a + a.T - 2/3*torch.eye(3) * (a.diag().sum()))[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]]
        x[i] = torch.tensor([xx - yy - 2j * xy, 
                             xz - 1j * yz, 
                             zz , 
                             xz + 1j * yz,
                             xx - yy + 2j * xy])
        a = R @ a @ R.T
        yz, xz, xy, xx, yy, zz = (a + a.T - 2/3*torch.eye(3) * (a.diag().sum()))[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]]
        y[i] = torch.tensor([xx - yy - 2j * xy, 
                             xz - 1j * yz, 
                             zz , 
                             xz + 1j * yz,
                             xx - yy + 2j * xy])
    return x, y

def get_M(R):
    x, y = make_l2(5, R)
    M = y.T @ torch.linalg.inv(x.T)
    return M


Spherical basis change.

It is a straightforward basis change as linked to the WP article. However, you have to permute the 2nd and 3rd entries to get to the conventional spherical basis with m= 1,0,-1, in that order for the Us given there, and apply these and their adjoints on either side of $S_{k,j}$, respectively.  You might first practice with $\ell= 1$ before this one, where you are only transforming one index of A.

Reassure the reader you have succeeded in working out the unitary transformation matrix $U^* $' described above and the $\ell =1$ warmup.

@CosmasZachos Thank you very much! By learning your reference I am sure the basis should be $(xx - yy)/2 - i xy, xz -i yz, zz, xz + i yz, (xx - yy)/2 + i xy$.

You seem to be in control of the transition from the Cartesian to the spherical basis, and vice versa. As a geeky service to the outside and future reader, I summarize my points in the comments, for the fundamental $\ell =1$ case, in full comportance with your
link
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_x \\
A_y \\
A_z
\end{pmatrix} =   \begin{pmatrix}
- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
- \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 \\
0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
A_+ \\
A_{0} \\
A_-
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
- \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0&- \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
A_+ \\
A_{0} \\
A_-
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
where the final transformation matrix is unitary, and hence
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=2r\sqrt{\pi/3} \begin{pmatrix}
- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
- \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0&- \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
Y^1_1 \\
Y^0_1 \\
Y^{-1}_1
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$

Thank you very much again! The basis for $l=2$ should be $(S_{00} - S_{11})/2 - i S_{S01}, S_{02} -i S_{12}, \sqrt{1.5}S_{22}, -S_{02} - i S_{12}, (S_{00} - S_{11})/2 + i S_{S01}$.I was almost right but missed the coefficient of $S_{22}$. After fixed it, the transformation matrix is unitary.
